# Remove space from default delimiter in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to iterate over a csv-like string : element;element;element;[...];element

So, I used this type of loop :

```
for %%a in (%%l) do (
     code ...
)
```

with %%a my elements and %%l my line.

It works but i got one problem. My element can have a space in it and the loop automaticaly count one element with space for two element. For example, if I got *05/05/2015 15:05:12* as an element, it will be parsed in two laps, *05/05/2015* then *15:05:12*. So, I want to remove the space as a splitter. Is it possible ?

Comment: Use a `FOR /F` instead.

Comment: With "delims=;", I iterate over the first element but not the others ...

Comment: Store `%%l` in an intermin variable like `set "LINE=%%l"`, then do this (supposing [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled): `for %%a in ("!LINE:;=";"!") do ( rem Use `%%~a` here to remove quotes. )`

Comment: The @aschipfl solution works, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` uses <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,`, `;`, `=` and the non-break space (ASCII `0xFF`) as delimiters (like `cmd` does too), unless they are enclosed within a pair of `"`.

We can make use of that:

```
rem The following is placed inside your `for /F` loop:
set "LINE=%%l"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in ("!LINE:;=";"!") do (
    rem Use `%%~a` here to remove quotes.
)
endlocal
```

The portion `"!LINE:;=";"!"` encloses a line in between `""` and replaces each delimiter `;` by `";"`, so we get a list of quoted `;`-separated items.

For example, the line...:

> ```
> element;05/05/2015 15:05:12;element
> ```

...becomes this:

> ```
> "element";"05/05/2015 15:05:12";"element"
> ```

Hence the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> appears in between a pair of `"`, so it is not considered as a delimiter anymore.

Note that [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) must be used here, because there is a variable (`LINE`) written *and* read within the same block of code, namely your `for /F %%l` loop.

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice explanation to go with your code !